# how to write into text file using command line argument in Python

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, file-handling

,
 i am having an issue when i tried to write a program in my Python. This is my requirement:
 1) Accept the input ( its a csv file ) as a command line argument 
 2) Read this csv file 
 3) count the num of words and characters from this csv file 
 4) and write the results - num of words and characters of the csv file into an another text file - say results.txt

this is what i tried"

```
  import sys
  print('the version of python')
  print(sys.version)


  with open(sys.argv[1], 'rt') as f, open(sys.argv[2],'r') as fw:
  contents = f.read()
  words= contents.split()
  print(' displaying words in txt file..', words)
  print(' number of words in txt file..', len(words))

  contents1 = fw.read()
  words1= contents1.split()
  print(' displaying words in txt file..', words1)
  print(' number of words in txt file..', len(words1))
```

am not getting the results. the first sections, reading of the file from the csv is working fine now.
but, how can i write into the results.txt file?

Comment: Why are you counting words from second file? Or are there two files to count words and in which case which is the file to write into?

Comment: here in the above code, i just tried for testing. what i need to show is, fetch the count of num of words, characters of the inputted file and write the same into a another results.txt file

Comment: Austin, no, there is only one file , that needs to be counted, that's the first input file and the num of words and characters of this input file should be written onto the newly created results.txt file..Can i create a new text file, if i give Results.txt file as a second command line argument and what code, i need to write in order to create a new text file  in Python.

Answer (score 1):

To write to a file you need to open it in "w" mode and then use `.write()` function to write the contents. Something like this:

```
file1 = open("myfile.txt","w") 
file1.write("Number of words: {}".format(len(words))
file1.close()
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: - @ghanasyam - , in my code, i used with keyword, so, how can i modify your code, in order to write into the new results.txt file